# Import Local Javascript Files into NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is it possible for a NodeJS Web Application to "import" and use a local Javascipt File's functions without using any middle ware modules?

EDIT:

cont.js

```
function getStyles(res,reqFile){
    var options={
                root:__dirname+'/Views/styles/',
                headers:{
                    'Content-Type':'text/css'
                }
            };

                res.sendFile(reqFile,options,function(err){
                    if(err){
                        console.log(err);
                        res.status(err.status).end();
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log("Sent "+ reqFile);
                    }
                });    
}
```

server.js

```
var fs = require('fs')
var path = require('path')
var express = require('express')
var app = express();
var url = require('url')
var views="/Views/"

app.get(/\/Views\/styles\//,function(req,res){
var reqPath = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
var reqFile = path.basename(reqPath); // the requested file
console.log("VIEWS/STYLES : " + reqPath);

fs.readdir(__dirname+views+'/styles','utf8',function(err,data){
    console.log(data);
    if(data.includes(reqFile)){
        console.log(reqFile+ " Found in data array" );
          //call function here
          getStyles(res,reqFile);
           }  

});
```

The relative path to server.js is : ./cont/cont.js

Comment: I think you're talking about have a web page that calls javascript function in node?  If that is the case, then no, the web app is running on the server and the only communication with client javascript code in the browser is through calls to the web server.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can just require('relative filename') and use the code but your cont.cont.js file must add an export

Something like:

cont.js

```
function getStyles(res,reqFile){
    var options={
                root:__dirname+'/Views/styles/',
                headers:{
                    'Content-Type':'text/css'
                }
            };

                res.sendFile(reqFile,options,function(err){
                    if(err){
                        console.log(err);
                        res.status(err.status).end();
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log("Sent "+ reqFile);
                    }
                });    
}

module.exports = getStyles;
```

server.js

```
var fs = require('fs')
var path = require('path')
var express = require('express')
var app = express();
var url = require('url')
var views="/Views/"

var getStyles = require('./cont/cont.js')

app.get(/\/Views\/styles\//,function(req,res){
var reqPath = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
var reqFile = path.basename(reqPath); // the requested file
console.log("VIEWS/STYLES : " + reqPath);

fs.readdir(__dirname+views+'/styles','utf8',function(err,data){
    console.log(data);
    if(data.includes(reqFile)){
        console.log(reqFile+ " Found in data array" );
          //call function here
          getStyles(res,reqFile);
           }  

});
```

Comment: Are you trying to have the server return (serve) the styles files to a browser in response to a web request?

Comment: I think I understand what you are trying to now, please check the edited answer